# How to synchronize content in databases across multiple Symfony projects?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm making a pretty complex project and I have a question about synchronizing entities, migrations, etc. between many Symfony projects.

Let's say I have three projects based on one database:

- User Panel
- Admin Panel
- API

All those projects use the same DB. Currently when I want to add something to a schema, I need to make it on one project and then copy the entity file to all other projects manually. It's fine if there is only one file to copy, but when I add many to many relations, it becomes annoying.

Is there a way to manage this in fewer steps or bulk copy the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a bundle that is used by all 3 projects which has all entities and migrations there.

But why do you need the same entities in 3 projects?If the projects are really this coupled that they share entities, IMO they should be merged into one project...

Comment: They need to be on separate servers.

Comment: @SzymonEllwart so what? make your database available for all those servers. it has little to do with Symfony itself, it's more like system administration problem.